# EF Core 3 Error when trying to save object with enumeration class properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I got a couple of entities that derive from a enumeration class (as described in this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/enumeration-classes-over-enum-types) 
Things like Genders, Countries.  Don't want to change this since it works really well.

Trying to implement EF Core 3 (I'm new to it, coming from dapper.net)

So I'd say have a Gender class:

```
public class Gender : Enumeration
    {
        public static Gender Female = new Gender(1, "Female");
        public static Gender Male = new Gender(2, "Male");
        public static Gender Unknown = new Gender(999, "Unknown");

        public Gender(int id, string name)
            : base(id, name)
        {
        }
    }
```

So in my DataContext I for instance have `public DbSet<Gender> Genders { get; set; }`

And seed the data in OnModelCreating:

```
private void SeedGenders(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            var values = Enumeration.GetAll<Gender>().ToList();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Gender>()
                .HasData(values);
        }
```

However later I'd say have `newPerson.Gender =   Gender.Female;` but then I try to save it with:

```
await  _repository.Insert(newPerson);
```

I will get  an error

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Genders' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Probably something simple but I cannot understand since I'm not trying to add anything to Genders, I'm trying to save an instance of a person.

My repository worked just fine until I started try add these enumeration classes with the following code

```
public async Task<Person> Insert(Person person)
{
    await _context.Persons.AddAsync(person);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return person;
}
```

Comment: Well you can avoid this behavior with attaching gender before you assign it to a person. This way EF will know it's an existing entity and you are just making relation. Else it will assume it's a new entity assigned and will try to create a new entity. For me it's an **ugly** solution. You may want to check `Owned` [types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities). You can convert your `Gender` type to an owned by person. And you can skip defining table for it.

Comment: oi did not see your comment. will give that a go.  at the moment it's working in a way i'm not comfortable with

Comment: ```public async Task<Person> Insert(Person person)
{
 person.Gender = _context.Genders.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == person.Gender.Id);

 //_context.Entry(potentialProvider.Gender).State = EntityState.Detached;
 // .. .the other "enums"
 await _context.Persons.AddAsync(person);
 await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
 return person;
}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set

```
newPerson.Gender =   Gender.Female;
```

That value (`Gender.Female`) is **new** to entity-framework.  It doesn't magically know it already exists in the database.  And it doesn't attempt to look for it either.  Entity Framework will attempt to save it to the database, and since it already has an Id value (not Zero) it tries to insert the gender and fails with that specific error.

You can fix your problem by telling entity framework not to save the Gender.

```
newPerson.Gender = Gender.Female
dbContext.Entry(Gender.Female).State = EntityState.Detached;
await  _repository.Insert(newPerson);
```

Tell EF that this entity is detached simply means, don't save it to the database.

Comment: Thanks so much Erik, that makes perfect sense, even to a noob.

Comment: Hmm..maybe there's another reason (though I'll try now to do it when i make the repository call, but did this in my insert method to avoid duplication).  Still get the same error

Comment: ```public async Task<Person> Insert(Person person)
{
 _context.Entry(potentialProvider.Gender).State = EntityState.Detached;
 // .. .the other "enums"
 await _context.Persons.AddAsync(person);
 await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
 return person;
}```